# karateframework:Pass values read from csv as arguments to javaprogram

Tags: javascript, java, karate

How to pass values as parameters dynamically to java program using karate framework.

I am trying to read the data from csv file. which is converted to json format

*Csv Data*

```
FirstName,MiddleName,LastName
"John","K","Kennady"
"Mahesh","g",Readdy"
```

```
* def csvData = read('csv Data')
* read csvData
```

Output of read csvData

```
[{"FirstName" : "John","MiddleName" : "K", "LastName" : "Kennady"},{"FirstName" : "Mahesh","MiddleName" : "g", "LastName" : "Readdy"}]
```

I am able to extract the values from json and the result looks like this

```
values = ["John", "K", "Kennady"]
```

I should pass the values as paramters to below command JavaDemo.doWorkStatic

```
* def JavaDemo = Java.type('com.mycompany.JavaDemo')
* def result = JavaDemo.doWorkStatic('Firstname','MiddleName','lastname')
```

in javascript we can assign array to array which can assign to arguments for java . But the below step is not possible in karateframework

```
[a, b ,c ] = Values
cosnole.log(a)
cosnole.log(b)
cosnole.log(c)
def result = JavaDemo.doWorkStatic(a,b,c)
```

**How can i acheive the final step passing the values as arguments**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
* def v = ['John', 'F', 'Kennedy']
* def result = JavaDemo.doWorkStatic(v[0], v[1], v[2])
```

Karate is *not* JavaScript. Please contribute code if you want to change anything.

EDIT: note that JSON arrays are auto-converted to Java `List`-s. Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java

For example if you have this:

```
public static String concat(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : list) {
        sb.append(s);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

You can do this:

```
* def array = ['a', 'b', 'c']
* def res = Utils.concat(array)
```

Comment: I have 20 - 30 fields that need to be passed to Javaprogram. I want the data to be read from csv file. reading csv file and looping the records, fetching the values from json in the  and pass them to javaprogram. some how

~~~
JavaDemo.doWorkStatic(v[0], v[1], v[2])
~~~~

is not working in javascript

Comment: @satishp5846 see my edit. if that does not help, karate is clearly not the right tool for you, so please find something else 

Answer (score -1):

```
* def csvData =
"""
function(arg){
var csvData = karate.readAsString(arg)
var data = csvData.split("\n")
   
   for(var i = 1; i<data.length; i++){
      var v = data.split(',')
      var JavaDemo = Java.type('com.mycompany.JavaDemo')
      var result = JavaDemo.doWorkStatic(v[0], v[1], v[2])

   }

}
"""

* csvData('sample.csv)
```

Comment: to others reading this - this is not a good example and lacks understanding of arrays, javascript, karate and the answer I suggested - fyi