# javascript: how to convert array to tuple

Tags: javascript

I have strange requirement in which i am using javascript.

I have json file from where i extract the values leaving keys. when i extract values I have them in array. **I should change the array to tuple**

in Python, we have and array and tuple concepts. But i am not sure about javascript.
Can anyone help one this

sample json

```
[ {a:1 , b:2}, {c: 3, D:4} ]
```

I am able to extract values for json array

my result is :

```
[1, 2]
```

and i want it to be as

```
 (1,2)
```

where i need to pass the (1,2) as arguments to java program

Comment: There are no tuples in JavaScript [yet](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple). The best you can do right now is an array of fixed size `[1, 2]` or an object with fixed properties: `{foo: 1, bar: 2}`

Answer (score 1):

```
let b = [1, 2, 3];
    
let ids = `('${b.join("','")}')`;

console.log(ids);
// "('1','2','3')"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As @vlaz write, there are no tuples but you have to use array like so:

```
var data = [ {a:1 , b:2}, {c: 3, D:4} ];
var result = [ data[0].a, data[0].b ];
```

Comment: I did ask the above question in refrence to the solution that i am trying to achieve in karate framwork

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718260/karateframeworkpass-values-read-from-csv-as-arguments-to-javaprogram

in short
1. I am trying to read data from csv and pass the data as arguments to javaprogram
2. by default the data read from csv is converted to json
3. extracted the values from json
4. I need to pass the values as arguments